# Data warehouse fact measurements that cannot be meaningfully aggregated over time?

Tags: data-warehouse

Is there an example of a time-varying numerical quantity that might be in a data warehouse that cannot be meaningfully aggregated over time? If so why?

Comment: What is the context of your question?  Are you just looking for help on your homework?

Comment: No. I was asked this in an interview and could not answer it nor find any credible answers on the net.

Answer (score 2):

Stock levels cannot, because they represent a value that is already an aggregation at a particular moment in time.

If you have ten items in stock today and ten yesterday, and ten in stock every day this week, you cannot add them up to "70" meaningfully for the whole week, unless you are measuring something like space utilisation efficiency.

Other examples: bank balance, or speed of flywheel, or time since overhaul.

Comment: Aren't these examples of non-additive facts? Couldn't they possibly be aggregated with a function other than sum() such as avg()?

Comment: Oh sure -- averages, maxima, minima etc.. But there's a general problem in data warehouses with non-additive metrics that I expect the questioner was referring to. If they truly meant metrics that cannot be aggregated at all then I doubt that there are any.

Comment: I can think of snapshot taken on unequal time intervals. But still you can apply min/max, but not sum, avg, percentile. I don't think there is any example where you can't apply man/mix.

Answer (score 0):

Many subatomic processes can be observed using our notion of "time" but probably wouldn't make much sense when aggregated. This is because our notion of "time" doesn't make much sense at the quantum level.